# Does VirtualProtect funtion needs admin privileges?

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi

VirtualProtect works fine on my xp, and win7 without any privileges, so why some dev keeps saying this function needs privileges ? 
is there any alternative to virtual protect ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be looking for alternative muses rather than alternative functions.

Comment: You can always change the protection flags in your own program.  It is using VirtualProtectEx() to mess with another process that is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualProtect not require any privileges.

Comment: hi, is there any oder way to edit protection of a region ?

Comment: @Waks - no. only VirtualProtect -> VirtualprotectEx -> ZwProtectVirtualMemory . nothing other exist. but why VirtualProtect  is bad for you ?

Comment: Why not contact MS and ask them to make a new API just for you

Comment: VirtualProtect works fine, sorry if i feel free to ask @DavidHeffernan.